# Full width background for sub-menu, but remain location

Tags: html, css, submenu

My question is really simple, but I can't find any efficient solution.
I just want to make my sub menu background (yellow in my case) full width.
I know I am placing the relative position in the wrapper, because that's what I want.(I want the sub menu to start just underneath the logo). [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xb9o31ce/32/)

The result I want - explained with image: [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LY54.jpg)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Navigation</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav id="main-nav">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1 class="logo">Site Name</h1>
      <ul class="main-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Item 2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2.3</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="left-menu">
        <li>Don't mind me.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#main-nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #EEE;
}

#main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

#main-nav .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

#main-nav ul.main-menu {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#main-nav ul.main-menu a {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#main-nav ul.main-menu a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}

#main-nav ul.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this neatly, you will probably have to re-construct the `nav-bar` into more defined components.

However a quick fix would be:

```css
#main-nav ul.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 125%;
  margin-left: -12.5%;
  padding-left: 12.5%;
}
```

Note that the above values only works with the dimensions you specified. If you want to change any of them, you will have to also modify the values in the sub-menu styling.

## EDIT

Another way would be to remove the wrapper div at all, and only rely on margins and padding for the elements that you need to center.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.left-menu {
  margin-right: 10%;
}

#main-nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #EEE;
}

#main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
}
 
#main-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

#main-nav ul.main-menu {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#main-nav ul.main-menu a {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#main-nav ul.main-menu a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}

#main-nav ul.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding-left: 10%;
}
```

If this doesn't work for you neither, you will probably have to use JavaScript to inject the sub-list into another container that is not contained by the wrapper.

Comment: Probably not the best solution and I would need to add `overflow-x: hidden;` in the body tag. What do you mean by re-constructing the nav, the only thing I can think of is adding a div inside a `<li>` tag and shuffling the wrappers a bit.

Comment: @al.cadastar I added another suggestion.

Comment: Can you show me example code for the JavaScript solution you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

you have to wrap `<ul class="sub-menu">` with `<div class="sub-menu-wrap">` and add this styles:

```
.sub-menu-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

and change the styles of `.sub-menu to`:

```
#main-nav ul.sub-menu {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/umsqo576/

Answer (score -1):

I added 3 lines to your final entry.  Expand the width to the full viewport, and then have to compensate for it starting 60 pixels from the left - margin-left -60px to move the yellow over to page edge, and then 60px of padding to have the text start where you want it.  Looked good on the jsfiddle when I was on there.

```
#main-nav ul.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: yellow; 
  padding-left: 60px;
  margin-left: -60px;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: Static values for padding and margins in pixels will make it too fragile. What works in your screen in pixels will not necessarily work on other screens sizes.